# Lidar Sensors not working properly - How to work with two lidar Sensors over I2C on arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm currently working on a project with some friends about lidar measuraments based on ARDUINO and GARMIN Lidar v3HP and we are getting some reading that are questionable from the sensors. They seem to work but the measurements are not correct.

We have issues with the data and also with the address, we setup the sensors with two different addresses 0x42 and 0x43, but one of the sensors keeps on the default address.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <LIDARLite_v3HP.h>
#include <I2CFunctions.h>

#define POWER_ENABLE_S1 12
#define POWER_ENABLE_S2 11
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS 98
#define FAST_I2C
#define NUMERO_LIDARS 2

LIDARLite_v3HP Sensor1;
LIDARLite_v3HP Sensor2;


int detectedAddreses[NUMERO_LIDARS];
int currentAdd;
int deviceCount = 0;
int i = 0;

void scanI2C()
{
    int nDevices = 0;
    while (i < NUMERO_LIDARS)
    {
        for (byte addr = 1; addr < 127; ++addr)
        {
            Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
            byte error = Wire.endTransmission();
            if (error == 0)
            {
                Serial.print("Se encontro un dispositivo en ");                
                Serial.print(addr);
                Serial.println("  !");
                ++nDevices;
                detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                if (addr == DEFAULT_ADDRESS)
                {
                    configSensors(i, 66 + deviceCount, addr);
                    detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                    i++;
                }else{
                  detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                  i++;
                }
            }
            else if (error == 4)
            {
                Serial.print("Error desconocido en ");
                Serial.println(addr);
            }
        }
        if (nDevices == 0)
        {
            Serial.println("No se encontraron dispositivos\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Terminado\n");
        }
    }
}

void configSensors(int sensor, uint8_t new_address, uint8_t old_address)
{
    switch (sensor)
    {
    case 0:
        Sensor1.setI2Caddr(new_address, 0, old_address);
        digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1, LOW);
        //detectedAddreses[sensor] = new_address;
        deviceCount++;
        Sensor1.configure(0,new_address);
        break;

    case 1:
        Sensor2.setI2Caddr(new_address, 0, old_address);
        digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2, LOW);
        //detectedAddreses[sensor] = new_address;
        deviceCount++;
        Sensor2.configure(0,new_address);
        i = 999;
        break;

    case 2:
        break;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    #ifdef FAST_I2C
        #if ARDUINO >= 157
            Wire.setClock(400000UL); // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz (for Arduino Due)
        #else
            TWBR = ((F_CPU / 400000UL) - 16) / 2; // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz
        #endif
    #endif
    pinMode(POWER_ENABLE_S1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(POWER_ENABLE_S2, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2, HIGH);
    Wire.begin();
    scanI2C();
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2,HIGH);
    Sensor1.configure(3,detectedAddreses[0]);
    Sensor2.configure(3,detectedAddreses[1]);
}

void measure(){
  float s1;
  float s2;  
  Sensor1.waitForBusy();
  Sensor1.takeRange();
  Sensor1.waitForBusy();
  s1 = Sensor1.readDistance(detectedAddreses[0]);  
  Sensor2.waitForBusy();
  Sensor2.takeRange();
  Sensor2.waitForBusy();
  s2 = Sensor2.readDistance(detectedAddreses[1]);
  Serial.println("Sensor 1: " + String(s1) + "; Sensor 2: " + String(s2));
  }

void loop()
{
 /*Serial.println(detectedAddreses[0]);
 Serial.println(detectedAddreses[1]);*/
measure();
  
}
```

Comment: my suggestion would be first get each working by itself.

Comment: @stark we done that many times, inverting the positions of the sensors, switched the Power enable pins, even switching arduinos

Comment: You've got an awful lot of hardwired "magic" numbers (e.g. `66 + deviceCount`). What is 66, 127, etc? Why don't you have comments and/or `#define` for these as you do for some other constants?

Comment: When you scan for a given `addr`, and hit the first one, how do you know that it's `Sensor1`? And, why bother to scan since you only do something if `addr` is `DEFAULT_ADDR` [which is 98]? So, the loop could just be `for (byte addr = 98; addr == 98; ++addr)` (i.e. your code will only configure _one_ sensor).

Comment: @CraigEstey i know about those magic numbers and i apologize, but i defined those so we can keep both sersors between 2 addreses which are 66 and 67, i'll probably will use a static array with those and use the counter "i" to determine the address for each sensor.

The sensors that we are working with use the same I2C address (0x62) that is how garmin configured the sensors from the factory and that's why i search for the 98 (decimal for HEX 0x62) which in theory, should change both of the sensors addreses to 66 and 67.

I've updated the code a bit to resolve some issues an array

Comment: You need to include the example output that shows the "issues".  What do you expect vs what you got.  I think the output text from `scanI2C` would be helpful as a minimum.  If I had to guess I would say two devices on the same I2C with the same default address is a problem.

Comment: Not in the office atm, but the output of the `scanI2C` (excluding any code inside the loop), shows:
`I2C device found at address 66`
`I2C device found at address 98`. The result is expected for the first sensor and not expected for the second one, even if we run the program again one of the sensors will stay at HEX `0x62` and not changing to HEX `0x63`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your top comment, there may be an issue with configuring both lidars at the same time.

From factory default, they will *both* respond to the default I2C address 0x62. So, when you try to reconfigure *one* at a time, they will *both* respond [and there may be a race condition] and will *both* get programmed to the new I2C address.

*If* [and this is a big if] the lidar can save the configuration to non-volatile storage on the unit, you can connect *one* at a time [physically/manually] and give them different addresses. The unit saves the address. And, next time, will only respond to the "new" address.

Then, after both units have been reconfigured, you can then connect both simultaneously and they will respond individually [as desired].

I looked at the `.pdf` and the wiring diagram. You may be able to connect the lidar's power pin [or enable pin] to an Arduino GPIO port pin (instead of +5V). Then, you can control the power up of each unit individually. Then, you can reconfigure both as above. That is, assert power to one, reconfigure it, power it down [with the saved config]. Do this for the other unit. Then, you can power up both units [at this point, they are responding to *different* I2C addresses].

Don't know if Garmin starts up the lasers immediately or whether you have to give it a "start" command. Being able to control power individually may be a good thing if there is *no* separate start command.

I'm not familiar with Garmin's lidars, but I've written S/W to control Velodyne lidars and we had to apply power in a staggered manner because the power surge when they *both* started up would "brown out" the system. With Garmin, YMMV.

If all else fails, you may have to put each unit on a separate/different physical I2C bus [because you can't reconfigure them separately].

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, we are now working on the issue and first thing we will try is to see if the power surge is where the sensors "stop working" properly, we will try to achive this providing power from an external source directly to the sensors.

About the configurations and the use of GPIO with the enable pin, we have that inside the configSensor function, where we pull down the EP of one sensor while we setup the address on the other.

Comment: Follow up from my last answer, after an hour of discussion and hooking up a 11.1V external battery with a power regulator to 5V, we were successfull to get proper measurements. also we did add the power enable switching to the measure function and a delay of 25 ms between switches, and it's working. THANKS YOU!!!!

I'll leave the code in case anyone comes up with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code,

The sensors are hocked up in the same I2C bus, power enable pins to each sensor and ground conected to arduino. Power to the sensors is supplied by a 11.1V battery with a power regulator to 5V

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <LIDARLite_v3HP.h>
#include <I2CFunctions.h>

#define POWER_ENABLE_S1 12
#define POWER_ENABLE_S2 11
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS 98
#define FAST_I2C
#define NUMERO_LIDARS 2

LIDARLite_v3HP Sensor1;
LIDARLite_v3HP Sensor2;


int detectedAddreses[NUMERO_LIDARS];
int currentAdd;
int deviceCount = 0;
int i = 0;

void scanI2C()
{
    int nDevices = 0;
    while (i < NUMERO_LIDARS)
    {
        for (byte addr = 1; addr < 127; ++addr)
        {
            Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
            byte error = Wire.endTransmission();
            if (error == 0)
            {
                Serial.print("Se encontro un dispositivo en ");                
                Serial.print(addr);
                Serial.println("  !");
                ++nDevices;
                detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                if (addr == DEFAULT_ADDRESS)
                {
                    configSensors(i, 66 + deviceCount, addr);
                    detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                    i++;
                }else{
                  detectedAddreses[i] = addr;
                  i++;
                }
            }
            else if (error == 4)
            {
                Serial.print("Error desconocido en ");
                Serial.println(addr);
            }
        }
        if (nDevices == 0)
        {
            Serial.println("No se encontraron dispositivos\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Terminado\n");
        }
    }
}

void configSensors(int sensor, uint8_t new_address, uint8_t old_address)
{
    switch (sensor)
    {
    case 0:
        Sensor1.setI2Caddr(new_address, 0, old_address);
        digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1, LOW);
        //detectedAddreses[sensor] = new_address;
        deviceCount++;
        Sensor1.configure(0,new_address);
        break;

    case 1:
        Sensor2.setI2Caddr(new_address, 0, old_address);
        digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2, LOW);
        //detectedAddreses[sensor] = new_address;
        deviceCount++;
        Sensor2.configure(0,new_address);
        i = 999;
        break;

    case 2:
        break;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    #ifdef FAST_I2C
        #if ARDUINO >= 157
            Wire.setClock(400000UL); // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz (for Arduino Due)
        #else
            TWBR = ((F_CPU / 400000UL) - 16) / 2; // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz
        #endif
    #endif
    pinMode(POWER_ENABLE_S1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(POWER_ENABLE_S2, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2, HIGH);
    Wire.begin();
    scanI2C();
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2,HIGH);
    Sensor1.configure(3,detectedAddreses[0]);
    Sensor2.configure(3,detectedAddreses[1]);
}

void measure(){
  float s1;
  float s2;  
  digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2,LOW);
  delay(25);
  Sensor1.waitForBusy();
  Sensor1.takeRange();
  Sensor1.waitForBusy();
  s1 = Sensor1.readDistance(detectedAddreses[0]);
  digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(POWER_ENABLE_S2,HIGH);  
  delay(25);
  Sensor2.waitForBusy();
  Sensor2.takeRange();
  Sensor2.waitForBusy();
  s2 = Sensor2.readDistance(detectedAddreses[1]);
  Serial.println("Sensor 1: " + String(s1) + "; Sensor 2: " + String(s2));
  }

void loop()
{
 /*Serial.println(detectedAddreses[0]);
 Serial.println(detectedAddreses[1]);*/
measure();
  
}
```